# Can this query with TypeORM have SQL injection?

Tags: sql, typeorm

We have a query to filter by title.

```
where: {
  title: Raw(
    alias => `${alias} LIKE :filtro COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`,
    {
        filtro: `%${params.filtro}%`
    }
  )
}
```

Am I in danger from SQL Injection?